# Passing sys props to Spark 1.5 especially properties with spaces in it

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, command-line

After using Spark 1.2 for quite a long time, I have realised that you can no longer pass spark configuration to the driver via the --conf via command line.

I am thinking about using system properties and picking the config up using the following bit of code:

```
def getConfigOption(conf: SparkConf, name: String)
    conf getOption name orElse sys.props.get(name)
```

How do i pass a config.file option and string version of the date specified as a start time to a spark-submit command?

I have attempted using the following in my start up shell script:

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=../conf/application.conf -DstartTime=2016-06-04 00:00:00"
```

but this fails at it space splits the command up.

Any idea how to do this successfully, or has anyone got any advice on this one?

I am EDITing this to show the bash script being used:

```
#!/bin/bash

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-/etc/hadoop/conf}

LIB_DIRECTORY=/opt/app/latest/lib/
ANALYSIS_JAR=spark-fa-2.16.18-standalone.jar
ANALYSIS_DRIVER_CLASS=com.spark.fa.Main
OTHER_OPTIONS=""
KEYTAB="/opt/app/keytab/fa.keytab"
PRINCIPAL="spark_K"


CLUSTER_OPTIONS=" \
--master yarn-client \
--driver-memory 2000M \
--executor-memory 5G \
--num-executors 39 \
--executor-cores 5 \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=200 \
--driver-java-options=-Dconfig.file=../conf/application.conf \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-DstartTime='2016-06-04 00:00:00'" \
--conf spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.9 \
--files /opt/app/latest/conf/application.conf \
--conf spark.storage.safetyFraction=0.9 \
--keytab ${KEYTAB} \
--principal ${PRINCIPAL} \
"
spark-submit --class ${ANALYSIS_DRIVER_CLASS} ${CLUSTER_OPTIONS} ${LIB_DIRECTORY}/${ANALYSIS_JAR} ${CONFIG} ${@}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes:

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=../conf/application.conf -DstartTime='2016-06-04 00:00:00'"
```

Comment: Quotes are not nested correctly. You open `"` in `CLUSTER_OPTIONS="` and close it later `--conf "` You should escape.

Answer (score 0):

If your parameter contains both spaces and single quotes (for instance a query paramter) you should enclose it with in escaped double quote \"

Example:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-DfileFormat=PARQUET -Dquery=\"select * from bucket where code in ('A')\" -Dchunk=yes" spark-app.jar
```